# Error while building Debian based docker image on Mac for a tool (dockerfile: FROM rocker)

Tags: docker, macos, build, dockerfile, debian

I want to run a tool (XYZ) which I downloaded from GitHub repo. Here is the docker file:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.0
#Use rocker from well maininted dockerhub as the parent image, will set up as a debian system
#debian:stretch

LABEL software.name="XYZ"
LABEL software.version="XYZ v1.0.0"
LABEL software.description="data_analysis"
LABEL container.base.image="debian"
LABEL tags="calls"

#Install necessary tools onto debian system
run apt-get update
run apt-get --yes install vim
run apt-get --yes install less
run apt-get --yes install parallel
run apt-get --yes install python-pip
run apt-get --yes install curl
run apt-get --yes install libpq-dev
    
#Install necessary R packages used in overlap script
RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('optparse', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('VennDiagram', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('gridExtra', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('dplyr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('readr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('DBI', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('RPostgres', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('dbplyr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('magrittr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('purrr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org/')"

#Install tools using pip that will be used in the analysis
run pip install awscli
run pip install boto3
run apt-get --yes install jq

COPY SCRIPTS /SCRIPTS

#ARG s3_folder=

# Run
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/bash",  "/SCRIPTS/overlap.sh"]

#CMD [ "--output_location", "test_data" ]
```

Now I am trying to build the docker image on Mac with command:

```
cd XYZ
docker build . -t XYZ
```

I am getting following errors on my terminal:

```
[+] Building 3.0s (6/27)                                                                                                docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.30kB                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/rocker/r-ver:3.5.0                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 1/23] FROM docker.io/rocker/r-ver:3.5.0                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 10.42kB                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [ 2/23] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                    2.9s
------                                                                                                                                       
 > [ 2/23] RUN apt-get update:                                                                                                               
1.122 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                   
1.143 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                                           
1.152 Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                                             
1.165 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                                                     
1.172 Ign:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
1.189 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
1.192 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
1.210 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
1.214 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
1.230 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
1.335 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
1.354 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
1.376 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
1.396 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
1.416 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
1.436 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
1.459 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
1.478 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
1.498 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
1.518 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
1.538 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
1.559 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
1.580 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
1.600 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
1.620 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
1.640 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
1.660 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
1.680 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
1.700 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
1.720 Err:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
1.720   404  Not Found
1.740 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
1.760 Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
1.760   404  Not Found
2.226 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
2.246 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
2.267 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
2.293 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
2.313 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
2.335 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
2.354 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
2.382 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
2.403 Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
2.424 Err:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
2.424   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.132 80]
2.431 Reading package lists...
2.447 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
2.447 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
2.447 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
2.447 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
2.447 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.132 80]
2.447 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
2.447 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     
  11 |     #Install necessary tools onto debian system
  12 | >>> run apt-get update
  13 |     run apt-get --yes install vim
  14 |     run apt-get --yes install less
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

I tried to install required dependencies with `brew` but does not help.
I know I need to change something related to Debian but was not been able to find that.

Internet is not the issue. It seems the issue of Debian with Mac, but I am unable to figure it out.

I would appreciate any advice on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: It seems `apt-get update` cannot access internet, have you checked if there is any network issue ?

Comment: Internet is not the issue. It seems the issue of Debian with Mac, but I am unable to figure it out.  I added to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Stretch is past its [end-of-life](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). You should upgrade to a newer release of Debian. If you really need to run unsupported versions, then you can pull packages from [Debian's archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76094428/596285).